# Enable Direct3D Accelaration

Tags: windows-7-x64, direct3d

How to enable Direct3D Accelaration in Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit?
(I've checked my Video driver and found that is uptodate)
[image]

Comment: It was enable by default. In your case, you should click the button "Run 64bit DxDiag" and see the Display tab.

Comment: I clicked on "Run 64bit DxDiag" and checked display tab. Still it shows Not Available.

Comment: I solved it, problem was with my driver software. I just updated to compatible one.

Comment: ***1 Hz***, huh? That has gotta be frustrating when the mouse cursor only moves 1 time a second...